# Kimchi Beef Noodles

Tags: beef, japanese-cuisine, noodles, korean-cuisine, kimchi

One of the things I really enjoy are those instant kimchi beef noodle soup bowls that you can get from the (American) supermarkets. Mostly because I like kimchi, I like beef, and I like noodles. Now I have found recipes for DIY kimchi beef noodle cups that you add boiling water to to make your own instant kimchi beef noodle soup, but I haven't found anything that's really a "from scratch" recipe. That got me thinking: Is kimchi and beef noodle soup a "thing"? More specifically, is it a traditional dish in Korean cuisine? Alternatively, is it a well known dish in Japanese or Chinese cuisine (because the noodles are pretty much ramen noodles in the instant soup bowls)?

Preferably the dish would be beef and necessarily include noodles, but if it is a hybrid/hodge podge that would be fine too. I just want to know what to search for for recipes because "kimchi beef noodles" isn't working for me.

Comment: Recipe requests are off-topic ... but maybe you could try Googling ... harder ... I found a few within a minute.

Comment: This question can be edited to eliminate the recipe request. I'll do it myself in a few hours if someone doesn't beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to answer the part of your question that isn't a recipe request.  I'm going to paraphrase it as:

> Is *X* a "thing" [in American cuisine]?

The answer, my curious friend, is a resounding **yes**... contingent on whether or not you make it.

We here in the States have the preposterously good fortune of having access to ingredients from all over the world and throughout various cultures.  The 'global pantry', so to speak, is more or less at our fingertips and within financial reach.  Most of the time, anyway.

[Chef Ed Lee](http://www.pbs.org/food/chefs/edward-lee/) of 610 Magnolia (Louisville, Ky.), has said much the same thing, and I think it rings true.

**You** *can* make [kimchi](https://www.google.com/search?q=kimchi&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), and [ramen](https://www.google.com/search?q=kimchi&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#safe=strict&q=homemade+ramen+noodles), and [stir fry beef](https://www.google.com/search?q=kimchi&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#safe=strict&q=stir+fry+beef), and [broth](https://www.google.com/search?q=kimchi&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#safe=strict&q=broth).

To borrow a phrase from the kids these days, f***ing google it!

Happy cooking!

:)